# Stored Procedure with multiple inner joins not returning when value is passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having an issue with an inner join. It executes but when I pass the value to it, it returns nothing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Get$Subject$For$Edit
(
@SubjectID int
)
as
select s.SubjectID, s.SubjectName, s.SubjectDescription, i.QuizID, i.GameID, i.VideoID, q.QuizID, q.QuizName, g.GameID, g.GameName,  
v.VideoID, v.VideoName
from [Subjects] s
inner join [SubjectInfo] i on i.SubjectID = s.SubjectID
inner join [Quiz] q on q.QuizID = i.QuizID
inner join [Games] g on g.GameID = i.GameID
inner join [Video] v on v.VideoID = i.VideoID
where s.SubjectID = @SubjectID
```

What am I missing or overlooking?

Comment: Are you sure the subject ID being passed exists?  Comment out the field list, change it to COUNT(*), then comment out each inner join.  I suspect one of the join isn't matching up.   Once the count goes from 0 to >0 (as you comment them out), you'll know which JOIN isn't OK

Comment: the query syntax is fine look closer into your data.

Comment: Hi guys, you are both right. I looked over my tables and realized that the video, games and quiz tables were empty and that was why my proc wasn't working. I totally overlooked that. Maybe its time I call it a night ;-)

Comment: Remember, inner joins on null fields will not match. You'll have to use outer joins where you expect there may be no corresponding value.

Comment: @reallythecrash that was exactly what I needed to use instead of the inner join, now I don't have to worry about whether or not the tables are empty.